# the same style.xml in two different Fragment not work

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I have this `Style.xml` in `res/values/values-v14`. In my `manifest` minSDK is 14.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
     <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/donostiakirolak_texto_general</item>

</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/donostiakirolak_actionbar_blue</item>
</style>



<style name="DonostiakirolakListView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/donostiakirolak_fondo_listview</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/donostiakirolak_texto_listview_title</item>


</style>
```

And i have two fragment very similar.

oneFragment `onCreateView` method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.instalaciones_en_lista_fragment, container, false);

    lvInstalaciones = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.instalaciones_en_lista_fragment_lvInstalaciones);
    lvInstalaciones.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    InstalacionesEnListaConFlechayCategoriasAdapter ad = new InstalacionesEnListaConFlechayCategoriasAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), this.instalacionesConCategorias, tag);
    this.lvInstalaciones.setAdapter(ad);
    return view;
}
```

TwoFragment `onCreateView` method: (**it is the same!**)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.instalaciones_en_lista_fragment, container, false);

    lvInstalaciones = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.instalaciones_en_lista_fragment_lvInstalaciones);
    lvInstalaciones.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    InstalacionesEnListaConFlechayCategoriasAdapter adapter = new InstalacionesEnListaConFlechayCategoriasAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), instalacionesConCategorias, tag);

    this.lvInstalaciones.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

this is `instalaciones_en_lista_fragment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/instalaciones_en_lista_fragment_lvInstalaciones"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        style="@style/DonostiakirolakListView">
    </ListView>
```

I specify style. Interestingly, the text display oneFragment is not the same color on the screen twoFragment. twoFragment is ok and oneFragment wrong.

**Edited**
This is `InstalacionesEnListaConFlechayCategoriasAdapter` code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = convertView;
    Instalacion inst = items.get(position);
    String nombre = inst.getNombre();


    //Analizamos si es necesario inflar el layout de la categoria
    if(nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(pldTraducido) //PLD
       || nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(cpfTraducido) //CPF
       || nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(frcTraducido) //FRC
       || nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(frdTraducido) //FRD
       || nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(otrTraducido) //OTR
       || nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(pldTraducido) //PLD
       || nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(ppeTraducido) //PPE
       || nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(psrTraducido)){ //PSR //Para que todas las instalaciones no recorran todos los ifs, s epodria mejorar el código. con interaces items y item.isSecction

         if (convertView == null || convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_categoria_header_titulo)==null)
            {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_header_categoria, null);
            v.setOnClickListener(null);
            v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            v.setLongClickable(false);

            }
            TextView nombreCategoria = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_categoria_header_titulo);
                    nombreCategoria.setText(nombre);

    }

    else{
        if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("DISTANCIA")){
            //Mostramos mojon y distancia
            //[Image+distancia][Nombre Instalación [Flecha]]
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_conflecha_mojon, null);
            TextView tvNombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_conflecha_mojon_tv_nombreinstalacion);
            tvNombre.setText(nombre);

            TextView tvTextoKm = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_conflecha_mojon_tv_texto_km);
            tvTextoKm.setText("km");

            TextView tvDistancia = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_conflecha_mojon_tv_distancia);
            tvDistancia.setText(inst.getDistancia());
        }else{

            //Sin mojon
            //[Nombre Instalación [Flecha]]
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_conflecha, null);
            TextView tvNombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_conflecha_tvnombreinstalacion);
            tvNombre.setText(nombre);

        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

and `custom_todaslasinstalaciones_conflecha.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_todaslasinstalaciones_conflecha_tvnombreinstalacion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/custom_todaslasinstalaciones_conflecha_img_flecha"
        android:text="Nombre instalación que pasa si el nombre d ela instalacion"
        android:textSize="18dp" 
        android:lines="4"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"/>

    <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/custom_todaslasinstalaciones_conflecha_img_flecha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "the text display oneFragment is not the same color on the screen twoFragment" you ment textColor for listView items, then maybe you should look at `your_list_item.xml` file for textColor properties or   `InstalacionesEnListaConFlechayCategoriasAdapter` for changing item text color code

Comment: I edited my post. it Is the same adapter and xml for two fragments